# How can I see user examples in Intents in IBM Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

So I am working with IBM Watson Assistant lite version.

When I give a user example in the intent, it's not showing up.
In Chrome and Microsoft Edge, I can actually see the scrollbar being very very tiny -
[image: Microsoft edge intent screenshot]

In Firefox, it is still not showing the user examples in the intent but the UI bug is different - I can't even see the scrollbar

- [image: Firefox intent screenshot]

I use Thinkpad T14 14 inch

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how can I see the examples??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced the same issue couple of times, it does not happen every time but when it happens you can zoom out the screen to see the examples.

Comment: This makes more sense than changing the whole resolution of the laptop

Answer (score 0):

It's the fault of the screen size.
I went to the display settings and changed the resolution to 1600x900 ppi and everything fell into the place.
But with a 14inch laptop - this resolution makes the text very small.
So I suggest just change the resolution when you need to work on them and go back to the previous resolution once your done so as to not harm your eyes. Or just try to zoom in whenever possible.